# How can i receive a message

Tags: c#, sockets, timeout, recv

I am maintaining a C# system, part of whose job is receiving tcp messages from random clients (using socket.recv()). We do have a message protocol,so that outsider developers could fill well formatted messages.

Message format as follows :

```
{ public data(fixed length):private data(variable length) }
```

To receive message ,we need a private data length field in this message, but someone need to send a message that may have fill in **wrong** length number.How can i fulfill this demand?

Here's my code:

```
public static int ReceiveMessage(int totalByteNumber, Socket socket, byte[] recvBuffer)
{
  try
  {
    int offset = 0;
    do
    {
      try
      {
        int num = socket.Receive(recvBuffer, offset, totalByteNumber - offset, SocketFlags.None);
        if (num == 0)
        {
          throw new ApplicationException();
        }
        offset += num;
      }
      catch (SocketException ex)
      {
        if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.IOPending || ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
          Thread.Sleep(30);
        else if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock)
        {
          socket.Blocking = true;
          Thread.Sleep(30);
        }
        else
        {
          LogManager.WriteError("Origin IP:" + (object) ((IPEndPoint) socket.RemoteEndPoint).Address);
          throw ex;
        }
      }
    }
    while (offset < totalByteNumber);
    return offset;
  }
  finally
  {
    SocketUtility.LogMessage("Recv", recvBuffer, socket);
  }
}
```

Comment: Simply if you cant read full message return error. Message must be well formated and filled.

Comment: You're right, but that's about company politics ....  So I just wonder ,technically speaking, is there a solution for that ?

Comment: You can read given bytes from port, try parse msg and if too short read more, merge with prev read, and try to find end message.

Comment: That's a good one.But we have not defined an ending flag  in the message protocol. Developers still have to modify their codes anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot accommodate incorrectly formatted messages, at least not reliably. TCP doesn't maintain message boundaries, so there's no way for you to know how long the message sent to you is.

In practice, if you typically have short requests and the requester sends the entire request in one send system call, there is a good chance each receive will return exactly one request message, but that's not reliable. For example, if the requester sends you two back-to-back, they might get coalesced before your process is scheduled so that both could be returned to you in a single receive call.

Your options:

- a length field in the message telling you how much to expect (most binary protocols work this way)
- some flag pattern in the message (null byte, or empty line of text, or whatever; text-based protocols like HTTP often work this way)
- end-of-file (i.e. caller could send a request, then call `socket.Shutdown(Send);`, you'd get EOF and know that's all to expect; obviously a one-shot deal this way)

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful.